# maven on shared drive for android studio dependencys always downloading due to in slow wifi

Tags: android-studio, maven, gradle, dependencies, offline-mode

I have a room of computers for developing apps with android studio they are all connected to a shared drive.
The internet in this room is slow, so it takes a long time for android studio to download dependencys when opening\creating projects.
I had a idea to use maven offline and put the repository on the shared drive for all the computers to access (so then i will only have to download everything once) but i dont know how to set up maven on a computer for this or to configure android studio so that it will use this repository rather then download them always, can someone please help by explaining in full how to set it up?
I downloaded maven offline from the android studio's website but I don't know how to set it up.
(please explain well I have no proire knolege in maven or gradle or android studio)

Comment: Best is to setup a repository manager and that will solve the problem... Using a shared drive is a bad idea...

Comment: can you please explain how I do this as I mentioned i am kinda knew to this. Thanks.

Comment: @khmarbaise if you could please explain thx

Comment: gradle saves all dependences in cache on your local machine. it is default. but you can use https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/installation-and-upgrades